# Ошибка при явном указании что переменная явояется экзмпляром класса

Tags: python

Здравствуйте у меня вопрос
у меня есть класс  `Application`

```
from fixture.client import ClientHelper

class Application:
        def init(self):
          self.client = ClientHelper(self)
```

и класс `ClientHelper`

```
class ClientHelper:
    def init(self, app):
        self.app = app
```

Во втором классе я хочу явно указать что app это экземпляр класса `Application`
Делаю импорт `from fixture.application import Application`
и в `def init(self, app: Application)`, при этом появляется ошибка

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Application' from partially initialized module 'fixture.application' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Можно ли как-то обойти эту ошибку, явное указание нужно чтобы idea понимала что это за переменная и корректно выдавала подсказки

Comment: Почему у Вас init   без '__'?

Comment: Не так написал( там должно быть __

Comment: В тексте ошибки же явный намёк на "циклический импорт". В модуле `А` импортируется модуль `Б`. А в модуле `Б` импортируется модуль `А`. Исправьте код так, чтобы такого не требовалось. Если вам только для указания типа, попробуйте взять его в кавычки `def init(self, app: "Application")` и не делать импорт. Это будет forward-declaration.

Comment: А других вариантов нет  ?
В моем случае нужно чтобы класс при интициализации передовал самого себя
А который я только создал принимал экзэмпляр этого класа и я явно указывал что это экзэмпляр этого класса